# Device that plays only the audio component of a TV signal

Tags: dsp, digital

Some radios have a TV dial, such as the *Tecsun R-909T*. But before purchasing, I tried to find a video demonstration of his work. I was confused by the fact that the work of a conventional radio is shown, but there is practically no work of the TV scale.

This led to the idea that the TV scale is either a marketing ploy, or such a receiver could once receive a TV signal, but the standards (wavelength, range, modulation type) have changed, and the receiver cannot work with them.

I have two questions:

1. Are there models of radio receivers that can still catch a TV signal in the meter and decimeter range? (Less preferred, since most countries are gradually moving to digital television).
2. Are there models of TV set-top boxes that have a signal from the TV cable at the input, and audio at the output, to which you can connect a training audio speaker, and switch channels and listen to "TV radio" with the control panel of the set-top box? (Preferably, as it covers a wider range of channels. It remains only to decide how to isolate the audio signal and play it on the speakers).

Answer (score 9):

In the U.S., analog TV VHF broadcasting ramped up around the early 1950's, but ended circa 2009-2011.  In analog TV broadcast signals, the audio portion was transmitted as an FM subcarrier inside the VSB signal containing NTSC television video.  Some radios manufactured could receive this FM audio.  But this signal isn't broadcast any more in the U.S.

Comment: Now analog television is completely fading away in many countries. Therefore, the option with a TV set-top box is preferable. I understand correctly that we can plug the cable out of the TV, plug it into this set-top box, connect speakers to the L / R audio inputs and listen, as it were, only to the sound from the TV?

Comment: @dtn some televisions have direct audio outputs, no box required!

Comment: I would like not to turn on the TV sometimes, i.e. "cable+box+remote+speakers" should give me sound from TV. A kind of TV radio

Comment: @dtn a bit confused now, your question is tagged [tag:analog-tv], but here you say you want to get the audio from *contemporary* TV, which is not analog. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, at the time of writing my question, I collected a decent amount of information in my head without structuring it, as a result of which I misled myself a little. After a few hours, the situation cleared up and now I'm leaning towards the scheme: "cable+box+remote+speakers" Let's keep discussing this issue.

Comment: @dtn If you have the cable and the box, then you plug the box into something that's not a TV. This is really easy if the box has a headphone or speaker output. Otherwise you may need to buy some adapter to extract the sound from the digital HDMI signal